# Why Swift object behaves differently when it is declared/not declared as property in Objective-C code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have some Swift class that present `ViewController` using some library. Here it is:

```
@objc class FloatingPanelAdapter: NSObject, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate {

@objc func present(vcToBeShown: UIViewController,
                   vcToPresent: UIViewController) {
    // init of panel from library
    let panel = FloatingPanelController()
    // setting vc that I want to display
    panel.set(contentViewController: vcToBeShown)
    // setting delegate
    panel.delegate = self
    // presenting
    vcToPresent.present(panel, animated: true)
}

/// FloatingPanelControllerDelegate method
func floatingPanel(_ vc: FloatingPanelController, layoutFor newCollection: UITraitCollection) -> FloatingPanelLayout? {
    /// FullFloatingLayout is my custom class that implements FloatingPanelLayout. I can show it if you want.
    return FullFloatingLayout()
}
}
```

Here is how I use above class:

```
- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {
   FloatingPanelAdapter *fpAdapter = [[FloatingPanelAdapter alloc] init];
   SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
   [fpAdapter presentWithVcToBeShown:vc vcToPresent:self];
}
```

When button gets pressed, I just initialize `FloatingPanelAdapter` and use it. The `SomeViewController` is presented successfully, but with not correct configuration. It is presented with default layout (not my `FullFloatingLayout`) of the `FloatingPanel` library. But the magic is when I declare my `fpAdapter` as a property:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
/* --- Importing Swift into Objective-C -- */
#import "SamplesObjC-Swift.h"
/* --------------------------------------- */
@interface ViewController ()
@property FloatingPanelAdapter *fpAdapter;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {
   self.fpAdapter = [[FloatingPanelAdapter alloc] init];
   SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
   [self.fpAdapter presentWithVcToBeShown:vc vcToPresent:self];
}
@end
```

Now my `SomeViewController` is presented fully, with right configuration from `FullFloatingLayout`. I don't leave here screenshots because it doesn't matter. I think the problem is that I don't use Objective-C(that I don't know well) correctly here. Why it behaves differently? What can be the problem?

Comment: It's because of `fpAdapter` scope. It will be release too soon, before the delegate method of `panel` `floatingPanel(_ vc:layourFor:)` get called.

Comment: How can I solve the problem? I don't want to have `fpAdapter` as a property. I want to create it inside function.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is that I don't use Objective-C(that I don't know well) correctly here. Why it behaves differently? What can be the problem?

No, it is not. The problem is in memory management.

```
- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {
   // here fpAdapter is created locally, so on quit this context it is destroyed
   FloatingPanelAdapter *fpAdapter = [[FloatingPanelAdapter alloc] init];
   SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
   [fpAdapter presentWithVcToBeShown:vc vcToPresent:self];
}
// >> here fpAdapter.dealloc
```

as soon as `fpAdapter` destroyed, the `delegate` of panel becomes `nil` because it is `weak` so does not keep reference of `fpAdapter`

```
    panel.delegate = self     // << here !!
```

So, to have `delegate` work you have to keep alive `fpAdapter` for the life-cycle of `panel`. And making it property is exactly does this

```
@interface ViewController ()
   @property FloatingPanelAdapter *fpAdapter;  // << keeps strong reference
```

Nevertheless where, but you must keep somewhere reference to `fpAdapter`!